# Can't figure a way to make this code right

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

i'm scraping this website with scrapy
https://www.rwaq.org/courses
but when i want all the data to be written in csv file
some data not in the right place
this website is in Arabic and it's about online courses
i want to scrape the information in the first page then go to
lecturer bio and **scrape** it too
and i want to **scrape** course details

i have tried this code but some information not inline with each other
i nearly know how to fix it but i can't know how -you know that feeling-

```
`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from ..items import RwaqItem


class XrwaqSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'xrwaq'
    start_urls = ['https://www.rwaq.org/courses']

    def parse(self, response):
        items = RwaqItem()
        container = response.css('#courses .row-fluid')
        base = 'https://www.rwaq.org'
        for t in container:
            course_name = t.css('h3 a::text').extract()
            course_time = [i.strip()[12:] for i in t.css('.course-info span::text').extract()]
            course_date_from = [c.strip()[3:17] for c in t.css('.subject-date::text').extract()]
            course_date_to = [c.strip()[28:] for c in t.css('.subject-date::text').extract()]
            course_lecturer_name = t.css('.lecturer-data span::text').extract()
            course_lecturer_bio_link = t.css("div.lecturer-data a::attr(href)").extract()
            course_category = t.css('.course-list-cat::text').extract()
            course_date = [r.strip() for r in t.css('p span::text').extract()]
            course_price = t.css('.course-price-tag-inner::text').extract()
            course_price_tag = t.css('.course-price-tag-inner span::text').extract()
            price = ''.join(course_price + course_price_tag)
            # print(course_date)
            course_link = t.css('h3 a::attr(href)').extract()
            for rw in course_link:
                url1 = base + rw
                # yield response.follow(url1, callback=self.parse_course)
            # print(url1)

            for item in list(course_lecturer_bio_link):
                url = base + item
                yield response.follow(url, callback=self.parse_bio)

            items['course_name'] = course_name
            items['course_time'] = course_time
            items['course_date'] = course_date
            items['course_date_from'] = course_date_from
            items['course_date_to'] = course_date_to
            items['course_lecturer_name'] = course_lecturer_name
            items['course_category'] = course_category
            items['course_link'] = url1
            items['price'] = price

            yield items

    def parse_bio(self, response):
        items = RwaqItem()
        bio_title = [we.strip() for we in response.css('div.page-title p::text').extract()]
        # bio_text = [wre.strip() for wre in response.css('div.bio-text ul li::text').extract()]
        # bio_text2 = [q.strip() for q in response.css('div.bio-text p::text').extract()]
        items['bio_title'] = bio_title
        # items['bio_text'] = bio_text
        # items['bio_text2'] = bio_text2
        yield items

    def parse_course(self, response):
        items = RwaqItem()
        course_promo_link = response.css('iframe::attr(src)').extract()
        course_desc = response.css('#summary_truncated p::text').extract()
        course_material = response.css('#organization > div.course-content > div:nth-child(4) ul li::text').extract()
        course_require = response.css('#organization > div.course-content > div:nth-child(5) ul li::text').extract()
        course_out = response.css('#organization > div.course-content > div:nth-child(6) ul li::text').extract()
        course_company = response.css('div.subject-organization p a::text').extract()
        # items['course_promo_link'] = course_promo_link
        # items['course_desc'] = course_desc
        # items['course_material'] = course_material
        # items['course_require'] = course_require
        # items['course_out'] = course_out
        # items['course_company'] = course_company
        # yield items
```

Comment: what error you getting?

Comment: i'm not getting any error the data is not in the right spot i want. data comes from  functions parse_bio and parse_course are not in the same line with data from function parse in excel. data in excel like write all data from parse() first then write data from parse_bio() and parse_course(). i want to loop over all functions and write it in excel once then loop again and again @Dev

Comment: what do you mean by this `i nearly know how to fix it but i can't know how -you know that feeling` ?

Comment: it is just feeling that i'm just too close to the answer @Dev

Comment: The idea is i want to scrap all the information in this site https://www.rwaq.org/courses then loop over every course like this link https://www.rwaq.org/courses/results_based_management and scrap it then loop over lecturer bio like https://www.rwaq.org/users/yaaqimad-20140826003621 and scrap it. i want to do all of this in a big loop so when export it to csv file all information for one course to be in on line and the second etc @Dev

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem is that you're yielding items, without linking the results of the different pages with eachother. An approach that could work is by adding the items to the meta, and only yield them when you have the full item info.
The below code should get you started - I also left out the unnecessary (at least I think they are) loops, and used extract_first() instead of extract() when appropriate.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from ..items import RwaqItem


class XrwaqSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'xrwaq'
    start_urls = ['https://www.rwaq.org/courses']

    def parse(self, response):
        items = RwaqItem()
        container = response.css('#courses .row-fluid')
        base = 'https://www.rwaq.org'
        for t in container:
            course_name = t.css('h3 a::text').extract_first()
            course_time = t.css('.course-info span::text').extract_first().strip()[12:]
            course_date_from = t.css('.subject-date::text').extract_first().strip()[3:17]
            course_date_to = t.css('.subject-date::text').extract_first().strip()[28:]
            course_lecturer_name = t.css('.lecturer-data span::text').extract_first()
            course_lecturer_bio_link = t.css("div.lecturer-data a::attr(href)").extract_first()
            course_category = t.css('.course-list-cat::text').extract_first()
            course_date = t.css('p span::text').extract_first().strip()
            course_price = t.css('.course-price-tag-inner::text').extract_first()
            course_price_tag = t.css('.course-price-tag-inner span::text').extract_first()
            if course_price and course_price_tag:
                price = ''.join([course_price + course_price_tag])
            else:
                price = ''
            items['price'] = price
            course_link = t.css('h3 a::attr(href)').extract_first()
            url1 = base + course_link
            items['course_name'] = course_name
            items['course_time'] = course_time
            items['course_date'] = course_date
            items['course_date_from'] = course_date_from
            items['course_date_to'] = course_date_to
            items['course_lecturer_name'] = course_lecturer_name
            items['course_category'] = course_category
            items['course_link'] = url1

            meta = {'items': items,
                    'bio_url': course_lecturer_bio_link}
            yield response.follow(url1,
                                  meta=meta,
                                  callback=self.parse_course)

    def parse_course(self, response):
        items = response.meta['items']
        course_promo_link = response.css('iframe::attr(src)').extract_first()
        course_desc = response.css('#summary_truncated p::text').extract_first()
        course_material = response.css('#organization > div.course-content > div:nth-child(4) ul li::text').extract_first()
        course_require = response.css('#organization > div.course-content > div:nth-child(5) ul li::text').extract_first()
        course_out = response.css('#organization > div.course-content > div:nth-child(6) ul li::text').extract_first()
        course_company = response.css('div.subject-organization p a::text').extract_first()
        items['course_promo_link'] = course_promo_link
        items['course_desc'] = course_desc
        items['course_material'] = course_material
        items['course_require'] = course_require
        items['course_out'] = course_out
        items['course_company'] = course_company
        bio_url = response.meta['bio_url']
        meta = {"items": items}
        yield response.follow(bio_url,
                              meta=meta,
                              callback=self.parse_bio)

    def parse_bio(self, response):
        items = response.meta['items']
        bio_title = response.css('div.page-title p::text').extract_first()
        if bio_title:
            items['bio_title'] = bio_title.strip()
        # bio_text = [wre.strip() for wre in response.css('div.bio-text ul li::text').extract()]
        # bio_text2 = [q.strip() for q in response.css('div.bio-text p::text').extract()]
        # items['bio_text'] = bio_text
        # items['bio_text2'] = bio_text2
        yield items
```

Comment: it's a good start but when i give it a try there are some duplicate data but thank you @Wim Hermans